# How does Hank Pym's (Earth-616) Yellowjacket suit allow him to fly?

Tags: marvel, avengers, technology, ant-man

How does the Yellowjacket suit fly? I remember the books saying that the disks on his shoulders enabled him to fly/hover thru vibration, I think. That always struck me as an unsatisfying answer because it didn't seem practical. Does anyone know the specifics of how this fictional tech works? Or even better would be how vibrations (if that is in fact the force involved) could create flight IRL.

Comment: thnx for cleaning up.:)

Comment: I've not read any of the Ant-Man/Yellowjacket comics, but his wiki page says Hank had actual wings on his Yellowjacket suit. Were the disks just a particular variation?

Comment: @Etheur I can't think of a time when I've seen that suit with wings. It normally looks like this: http://www.flickeringmyth.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/marvel-comics-yellowjacket.jpg I'd describe those things on his shoulders as arches rather than disks, but either way, they're not wings.

Comment: In this image, you can see those shoulder arches vibrating; https://marvelsmartass.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/yj.jpg?w=640

Comment: A scientifically valid answer is that when shrunk, the fact that the air is relatively thicker for the suit would allow it to move by a vibratory style propulsion - the way bacteria move by waggling a long hair-like structure called a flagellum. A vibrating plate might drive the suit in the same way.